# perf stat frontend and backend cycles showing greater than 100%

Tags: c, profiling, x86-64, perf

I'm trying to benchmark a piece of code written in C using `perf` and I get over 100% in the frontend idle cycles count. I've seen this happen for the backend idle cycles count as well. Both over 100 at the same time. The number of instructions per cycle is a pretty high amount - ranging from `5 - 10`.

```
3,569,966 stalled-cycles-frontend   #  111.98% frontend cycles idle   
1,843,327 stalled-cycles-backend    #   57.82% backend  cycles idle   
17,875,020 instructions             #    5.61  insns per cycle        
                                    #    0.20  stalled cycles per insn
```

What does it mean when the percent is so high?

Comment: Let me guess, you have a multi-core processor? Because of this it's often easy to get percentages over 100%.

Comment: Yes, I do. So how should I interpret this? Or just disregard it entirely?

Comment: Try running your command only on one cpu. That probably will prove that its multi-core which is messing the percentage number.

Comment: Danny, `stalled-cycles-frontend` may be defined not as cycles for you CPU. What is the exact CPU model on the machine?

Comment: Modern `perf` counts `cycles` across all threads, just like `instructions`.  So calculated IPC is realistic, and the average across threads.  This sounds like an old weird problem that doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

These percentages are with respect to active CPU cycles, which is displayed as `cycles`. So, `cycles` is not the total cycles but the active CPU cycles, and front-end or back-end stalled cycles are computed with respect to it.